# D3 geojson map mouse event triggering "poorly"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, geojson, choropleth

I'm creating a choropleth with D3 from geojson. Map has mouseover and mouseout events tied to counties. Problem: events are triggered only when mouse is slowly and precisely moved on the path that makes up counties. If I move mouse over the map more quickly the events are not triggered at all. When mouse crosses the county line only one event is triggered. Essentially I want to tie the events to the areas that represent counties and not to the lines/path that draw them. I have made same kind of map before for US counties and using the same approach and mouse event functions the result was that events were triggered smoothly. So I think it has to do with the svg/map not my approach?

Also tried using topojson but it made no difference. The geojson file is converted from shp file with EPSG:3301 projection.

```
let width = 1000;
    let height = 550;

    let svg = d3.select('#viz')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)

    let tooltip = d3.select('#viz')
                    .append('div')
                    .attr('id', 'tooltip')

    let projection = d3.geoIdentity()
                        .reflectY(true)


    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keijop/counties_geojson/main/maakond_20210301.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            
            console.log(data)
            
            projection.fitSize([width,height], data)

            svg.selectAll('path')
                .data(data.features)
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
                .attr('data-county', d => d.properties.MNIMI)
                .attr('data-ehak', d => d.properties.MKOOD)

                .on('mouseover', (e,d) =>{
                    console.log(e.target)
                    d3.select('#tooltip')
                        .style('top', e.pageY+10+'px')
                        .style('left', e.pageX+10+'px')
                        .style('opacity', '1')
                        .html(
                            e.target.getAttribute('data-county')
                            )
                        e.target.style.fill = 'yellow'
                    })

                .on('mouseout', (e,d) => {
                    e.target.style.fill = 'none'
                    d3.select('#tooltip')
                        .style('opacity', 0)

                    })
        });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrnp3xq9/.
Desired outcome: https://codepen.io/KeijoP/pen/VwPZMmb

Comment: Use `pointer-events: all;` in your paths: https://jsfiddle.net/1wmgqxzn/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for the help! Do you know why in my previous project this functionality worked without `pointer-events: all;` In here https://codepen.io/KeijoP/pen/VwPZMmb

Comment: Because those paths had a `fill`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again!